# Need help to extract the name of person

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm extracting data from a website and I want to get the names of students in a proper form.

How I can change `\xa0  RAJAT KUMAR\r\n                                '`
into `RAJAT KUMAR`.

Comment: Slice the string. If all of them are in this exact pattern, you can use `newstr = oldstr[2:-2]`

Comment: `"\xa0  RAJAT KUMAR\r\n                                '".replace("'", "").strip()`?

Comment: Your question doesn't show own effort, isn't clear (what general form has the input to process?) and isn't related to scraping or web at all.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you are obtaining the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strip() that will help you for this.

```
string = '\xa0  RAJAT KUMAR\r\n                                '
print(string.strip())
# RAJAT KUMAR
```

if it fails try to use this function , it will helpful.

```
def RemoveMeta(string):
    import re
    string = re.sub('\s+',' ',string)
    string = re.sub('\n|\t|^\s+\|\s+$','',string)
    string = string.strip()
    return string
print(RemoveMeta(string))
# RAJAT KUMAR
```

Also if you have any encoding or text issues you can include below that will help you,

```
import ftfy
string = ftfy.fix_text(string)
```